# Fallback support for recording without laravel

Tags: laravel, fallback

There is a table construction as below.

**Page Table**

| ID | Active |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | true |
| 2 | true |

**Page Translate Table**

| ID | Page_ID | Language | Title |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | tr | Merhaba dunya! |
| 2 | 1 | en | Hello World! |
| 3 | 2 | tr | Merhaba! |

**PageController.php**

```
$page = Page::with(['translate' => function ($q) {
    $q->where('language', 'tr');
}]);
        
echo $page->translate->title;
```

**Page.php (Page Model)**

```
public function translate()
{
    return $this->hasOne(PageTranslate::class);
}
```

My relationship patterns are like this. There are 2 records of the relevant records in Turkish and English, but not one.

When no Turkish record is found, I want it to automatically record in English.

Attribute is not working for me. WithDefault, on the other hand, sends the request to MySQL whether it finds it or not.

How can I achieve this? Thank you from now.

Answer (score 0):

You could add another relationship that points to the English translation.

```php
public function englishTranslation()
{
    return $this->hasOne(PageTranslate::class)->where('language', 'en');
}
```

Then, use it like this:

```php
$page = Page::with(['englishTranslate', 'translate' => function ($q) {
    $q->where('language', 'tr');
}]);
        
echo ($page->translate ?: $page->englishTranslate)->title;
```

Comment: This is a method but there are many keys that I will output JSON. Fallback needs to be done automatically. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Page hasMany translations not hasOne. So:

**Page.php (Page Model)**

```
public function translations()
{
    return $this->hasMany(PageTranslate::class, 'Page_ID', 'ID');
}
// You must take $currentLocale variable from user(Header, Browser, Settings etc.) with fallback locale. Check LaravelLocalization. 
public function translation()
{
    return $this->hasOne(PageTranslate::class, 'Page_ID', 'ID')->where('language', $currentLocale);
}

public function translationByLocale($language = "en")
{
    return $this->hasOne(PageTranslate::class, 'Page_ID', 'ID')->where('language', $language);
}
```

Comment: What I am looking for is that it will be replaced automatically when there is no recording.This is not the method I was looking for.